# update mysql results frequently node js

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am working on a web app and I am using node js and mysql. I am still learning node js. I was trying to perform queries using mysql in the js file and it worked. However it only works when i refresh the page. I want it to update the results of the query every duration of time and not when i refresh the page. How can i do that? Thank you very much!

here is the code in my js file

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mysql = require('mysql');
var async = require('async');

var pool = mysql.createPool({
connectionLimit : 10,
host            : 'localhost',
user            : 'root',
password        : 'AK94',
database          : 'aubookit'
});


/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
pool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
    async.parallel([
        function (callback) { connection.query('select * from Librarians', callback) },
        function (callback) { connection.query('select * from Students', callback) },
        function (callback) { connection.query('select * from reservations', callback) }
    ], function (err, results) {

        res.render('index', { title: 'BookIT', Librarians: results[0][0], Students: results[1][0]});
        connection.release();
    });
});
});


router.get('/LibrarianPage', function (req, res, next) {
res.render('librarian', { title: 'Librarian Page' });
});

router.get('/StudentPage', function (req, res, next) {
    pool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
        async.parallel([
            function (callback) { connection.query('select * from reservations', callback) }
    ], function (err, results) {

        res.render('student', { title: 'Student Page', reservations: results[0][0] });
        connection.release();
    });
});

});

module.exports = router;

router.get('/LibrarianPage', function (req, res, next) {
    res.render('librarian', { title: 'Librarian Page' });
});

router.get('/StudentPage', function (req, res, next) {
    res.render('student', { title: 'Student Page' });
});

module.exports = router;
```